# activeMQ Receiver rewind missing?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I have a queue producer which works fine.
I have a queue receiver which works fine.

This issue is this.  If I start the producer and it starts pumping data into the queue and some amount of time later I start the receiver it only seems to to fetch data that comes along AFTER I start the receiver, so items in the queue that were placed there before the receiver started never get pushed.

Is there a way to tell the receiver to start at the beginning of the queue regardless of the start time of the receiver? I have reviewed the methods of the receiver class and don't really seem to see anything there suggesting a way to do so.

Your help is very much appreciated.

Some additional information was requested...

```
The receiver...

      int x = 0 ;
        while(x < 1000 ) {
            // receive a message
            TextMessage message = (TextMessage) queueReceiver.receive();

            // print the message
            System.out.println("received message : " + x + " " +message.getJMSMessageID());

            x++ ;
        }
        // close the queue connection
        queueConn.close();
```

The producer code is a lot more complex is not so easily posted as it is contained in more than a few classes, but here is the queue creation portion:

> public class qDestinations {
>
> ```
> public static Queue createDest(Session session, String destName) {
>
>
>     try {
>         return session.createQueue(destName);
>     } catch (JMSException e) {
>         System.out.println(e.getMessage());
>         return null;
>     }
>
> }
> ```

I hope this helps to solve this question.

> }

Comment: Since it sounds like you are mistakenly using a TOPIC and not a QUEUE I suggest supplying more information, code for example to show what you are doing.

Comment: No it is very definitely a queue, using the cerateQueue("test") call. for the producer and the synonymous call in the receiver.

Comment: Do you happend to set JMSExpiration? Maybe your messages expires? A queue does not get rid of messages unless they are consumed or expires. A consumer does not receive messages from "the middle" of the queue, it's always FIFO unless you do something strange with JMS Selectors.

Comment: Not enough to really help you I'm afraid.  Queues should retain messages until consumed.  If the message is being sent non-persistent and the broker is restarted that could explain loss.  Otherwise messages could be sitting in the prefetch buffer of another receiver if you are using more than one.  Need more insight into the use case to know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

This is a strange answer but I had been setting TTL on each message into the queue and it seems as though even thoug TTL had expired, according to the AMQ Management console these items were still in queue.  So I set TTL for an hour an the problem has been mitigate.

Thanks to all who scratched their collective heads on this one.